# Analysis Services with Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, analysis, visual-studio-2022

I installed visual studio 2022 with all the necessary extensions for the analysis service but when I want to create a project in visual studio I do not have the ability to create a tabular project. Do I need to install anything?

Comment: Not supported yet, neither is reporting projects, https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Add-SQL-Server-Reporting-Services-and-SQ/1574249, I would expect them to be released at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue. Found this: [docs.microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/620487/problem-with-analysis-services-in-visual-studio-20.html)

> The extensions for Analysis Services, Integration Services, and Reporting Services projects are not available for Visual Studio 2022 at this time.

Comment: Then here's a monkey wrench. why do certain extensions for VS 2022 reference the model explorer - a feature provided by SSDT?

Answer (score 0):

By now, you can use the preview extensions for vs 2022, according to the link below.
[https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftAnalysisServicesModelingProjects][1]

> Navigate to Tools > Options and then select Extensions and Updates under General. Under "Additional Extension Galleries", enter the following details: Name: Microsoft BI VSIX Preview URL: http://aka.ms/ProBI-VSIX2022 After entering these settings, your "Extensions and Updates" dialog will show updates for the extension when there is a new release candidate that you can install to provide feedback for a day or two before the VS Gallery VSIX is updated.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31443762)

Answer (score 0):

The extension is now released in Visual Studio Gallery at https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftAnalysisServicesModelingProjects2022.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31796995)